# when am I safe to query a View's dimensions?

Tags: java, android, runtime, android-imageview

I'm trying to grab the dimensions of a view in my activity. The view is a simple custom view which extends an ImageView:

```
<com.example.dragdropshapes.CustomStrechView
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:background="@drawable/border"
     android:src="@drawable/missingpuz"
     android:clickable="true"
     android:onClick="pickShapes"
     />
```

I need to know what the specific "fill_parent" ends up being. I attempted to get this information during the `onCreate` method of the Activity using the layout containing my custom views:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_puzzle_picker);
    // Show the Up button in the action bar.
    setupActionBar();
    int a = findViewById(R.id.pickshapes).getMeasuredHeight();
    int b = findViewById(R.id.pickshapes).getHeight();
```

In this case, both `a` and `b` return a value of 0. Later, the custom view will be used as a button (it has an onClick handler) so I thought to try again to get the size in the handler:

```
public void pickShapes(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ShapesActivity.class);
    int a = findViewById(R.id.pickshapes).getMeasuredHeight();
    int b = findViewById(R.id.pickshapes).getHeight();
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Here `a` and `b` both give valid dimensions... I don't want to wait for a "onClick" event however, I want to get the dimensions as soon as possible. I've tried Overriding both `onStart()` and `onResume()` to check the dimensions as well, but in both cases I still get 0.

So my question is, where in the Android Activity start up flow, is the first place I can get the actual size of a View? I want to be able to get the height/width as soon as I can, and I want to do it before the user has a chance to interact with the environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a fairly useful thing in Android called the `ViewTreeObserver`. I've done precisely what you need to do many times this way. As you've discovered, you need to wait until at least the measure cycle completes. Try something like the following:

```
...
setContextView(R.layout.activity_puzzle_picker);

final View view = findViewById(R.id.pickshapes);
view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        int height = view.getMeasuredHeight();
        if(height > 0) {
            // do whatever you want with the measured height.
            setMyViewHeight(height);

            // ... and ALWAYS remove the listener when you're done.
            view.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        }                          
    }
});
...
```

(Note that you haven't set the id of your view in your XML... I'm using `R.id.pickshapes` because that's what you chose.)

Comment: That's really cool, almost exactly what I needed... any idea what was done instead of `removeOnGlobalLayoutListener()` prior to API level 16?

Comment: Found it, the `On` goes on the other side of `Global` for the old API (ie `removeGlobalOnLayoutListener()`) with that tweak, and a check for SDK version, I'm set! Thanks very much!